# mySQL : insert a row dynamically in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert a row in a table dynamically.

---

I've got this array:

```
Array
(
    [datas] => Array
        (
            [col1] => Lorem
            [col2] => Ipsum
            [col3] => Dollor
        )

    [actions] => Array
        (
            [table] => ExampleTable
        )
)
```

Each item in `datas[]`, corresponds to my column in the table `ExampleTable`.

```
|------|------|------|
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|------|------|------|
```

---

I would like to generate the query and its execution.

```
// Prepare
$prepare = '';
$prepare .= 'INSERT INTO ___'.$arr['actions']['Table'].' VALUES(';
foreach($arr['datas'] as $row => $data) { $prepareDatas[] = ':'.$row; }
$prepare .= implode( ', ', $prepareDatas);
$prepare .= ')';

$query = $pdo->prepare($prepare);

// Execute
foreach($arr['datas'] as $row => $data) {
    $query->bindValue(':'.$row, $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$query->execute();
```

But it doesn't not work.

Do you know why ?

---

**Why I can 't use the normal way ?**
Just because I'm trying to create something I can use for all my form. I do not want to create a new query for each one.

---

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Nick, the query is working but I don't have any value associated. I dont' have anything in the `error_log`.

Comment: In your example array you have a key called `table`, but when you build the query you call `Table`. Case matters. Is this an error you made in the question or this in actual code?